# Sharepoint rest api get request using python returns 401

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to fetch details from sharepoint rest api using get request.
Using Java I am able to get the details with using any credentials.
However when trying from python I get 401 error
Is it possible to access it without sending credential

```
Python Code:
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth


headers = {
"Accept":"application/json; odata=verbose",
"Content-Type":"application/json; odata=verbose",
"odata":"verbose",
"X-RequestForceAuthentication": "true",
"Connection":"Keep-alive",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":'1',
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
}


auth = HttpNtlmAuth('username','password')
response =requests.get("url", auth=auth)
print("--------",response.request.headers)
for r in response.history:
    print ("--------",r.headers)
print(response)

Response:
------- {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'Ke
ep-Alive', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.17.3', 'Authorization': 'NTLM TlRMTV
NTUAADAAAAGAAYAGYAAAAYABgAfgAAAAIAAgBIAAAADAAMAEoAAAAQABAAVgAAAAAAAACWAAAABYKIog
UBKAoAAAAPLgBhAGMAbgByAGYAcwBMADAAMQA0ADIAMQAxADMAItYC2wYJ7G4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AA8n1+n9UWFFRUMQzjMj8muwmYNCYfa91n'}
-------- {'X-FRAME-OPTIONS': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', 'SPRequestDuration': '3', 'SPIisLat
ency': '0', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Negotiate, NTLM', 'X
-MS-InvokeApp': '1; RequireReadOnly', 'Content-Length': '16', 'X-SPWFE': 'W00025
0', 'Date': 'Tue, 13 Jun 2017 10:03:18 GMT', 'SPRequestGuid': '5231fb9d-1eac-002
a-e59e-04fcc12587ee', 'request-id': '5231fb9d-1eac-002a-e59e-04fcc12587ee', 'Mic
rosoftSharePointTeamServices': '15.0.0.4763', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5'}
-------- {'X-FRAME-OPTIONS': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'SPRequestDuration': '1', 'X-Content-
Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'WWW-Authenticate': 'NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAADAAMADgAAAAF
gomiXpOD7CdoaSEAAAAAAAAAALIAsgBEAAAABgOAJQAAAA9DAEcAVQBTAEUAUgACAAwAQwBHAFUAUwBF
AFIAAQAOAFcAMAAwADAAMgA1ADAABAAmAGMAZwB1AHMAZQByAC4AYwBhAHAAZwByAG8AdQBwAC4AYwBv
AG0AAwA2AHcAMAAwADAAMgA1ADAALgBjAGcAdQBzAGUAcgAuAGMAYQBwAGcAcgBvAHUAcAAuAGMAbwBt
AAUAGABjAGEAcABnAHIAbwB1AHAALgBjAG8AbQAHAAgAqlFmSCzk0gEAAAAA, Negotiate', 'SPIis
Latency': '0', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices': '15
.0.0.4763', 'Content-Length': '0', 'X-SPWFE': 'W000250', 'Date': 'Tue, 13 Jun 20
17 10:03:18 GMT', 'SPRequestGuid': '5231fb9d-0eaf-002a-e59e-0ff3040d6d28', 'requ
est-id': '5231fb9d-0eaf-002a-e59e-0ff3040d6d28', 'X-MS-InvokeApp': '1; RequireRe
adOnly', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth

r=requests.get("https://example", auth=HttpNegotiateAuth(), verify=False)
```

That should do it.